# DateTime.Add(TimeSpan) performance vs DateTime.AddDays/Hours/etc* methods

Tags: .net, datetime

Is there any performance difference in using `DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)` vs. `DateTime.AddDays(double)`, `DateTime.AddHours(double)`, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add(TimeSpan) calls AddTicks directly with the ._ticks member of the TimeSpan.  AddDays, etc., do a multiplication and range check, then call AddTicks.  So Add(TimeSpan) is probably fractionally faster, but almost certainly insignificantly so: all will be blindingly fast.

Comment: Indeed, there's not much expensive going on there.  I took Yuriy's advice re: reflector and see what you're saying here.  Just for fun, I ran Add and AddDays through 10 million runs.  Add took 1.7 seconds, AddDays took 4 seconds.  Definitely fast.  Negligible, really.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This simple benchmark indicates that using a TimeSpan **might** be a bit faster, but both are extremely fast, doing 10 million iterations in under a second.  Execution time will be swamped by other aspects of your code.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)] 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw= new Stopwatch();
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        DateTime d2 = d.AddHours(10);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        DateTime d2 = d + new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

> // Core2 Duo, Win7. Ratio holds up under repeated tests
>   00:00:00.4880733 // AddHours
>   00:00:00.4404034 // add TimeSpan

Comment: I like your test code a lot more than mine.  Thanks, Michael.

Comment: No garbage collection between them?

Answer (score 0):

dattimeadd(timespan) is, in fact, a little faster than datetime.adddays and addhours, but not enough to matter in almost any practical case. At 500,000 iterations, it's inconclusive. At 2,000,000 iterations, you can see a difference.